# What is the VBA syntax to access hidden tables in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a list of all tables in an ms Access database including those that are hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will print the name of each table to the immediate window.

```
Sub ShowAllTables()

    Dim obj As AccessObject

    For Each obj In Application.CurrentData.AllTables
            Debug.Print obj.Name
    Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: You should exclude System tables - they start with MSys - from any actions on tables, tampering with system tables can permanently damage or destroy your database. 

If Left(obj.Name,4) <> "Msys" Then
  'Do stuff
End If

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether an AccessObject can tell you whether the table is hidden but ADO certainly can e.g.

```
Sub ShowAllTables2()

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim t
    For Each t In .tables
      Debug.Print t.Name, t.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Table Hidden In Access").Value
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```